# perforce doesn't overwrite file when forcing revision

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

My problem is not the "scary" issue of perforce overwriting my files, but the opposite, that it **doesn't**.

I want to be synchronized with code other people wrote, so I am doing in perforce: "***get revision***" and then "***force operation***" from the stream everyone are submitting their work to (after saving a backup of course for the file I am working on in my computer), but when I open the file in eclipse it remains with my changes.
Further - I am doing some small, deliberate changes in my file, and "*get revision*" and then "*force operation*" to it, and the same happens.

I have been working in the same workspace for the last days, and when I did it yesterday it overwrote my files, as expected.

Also, in the "*submitted*" tab in Perforce this file is not in the list, so I didn't accidentally submitted it somehow.

Also, by opening the file from the *File System*, my changes remain, so it doesn't seem like a problem with eclipse refreshing or something like that.

Ay idea, anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file is recorded as "open" in Perforce (i.e. it is returned by the "p4 opened" command, or it appears in the "pending changes" tab in the GUI), even a force-sync won't overwrite it, because you're still working on it.  If you want to discard your changes to get something someone else submitted, do one of these two things:

- Sync as normal, then resolve with "accept theirs".
- Sync as normal, then revert.  (Or revert, then sync.)

The first option leaves the file open; the second option does not.

If you want to save a backup of your current work in Perforce (without submitting it), rather than making a local copy of it, you can "shelve" the pending changelist, and "unshelve" it at a later date to return your workspace to the shelved state.